Définition d'abattage dans un dictionnaire potentiellement inexacte
Bonjour,
Je suis débutant en français et en apprenant de nouveaux mots, j'ai rencontré un terme dans un dictionnaire.
J'y ai trouvé le mot abattage avec la définition suivante :
"Abattage (m) : tissu ou papier qui enveloppe une lampe pour rabattre la lumière trop vive pour les yeux."
Cependant, cela m'a un peu déconcerté, car d'après mes recherches (notamment sur Google), cette définition semble plutôt correspondre à abat-jour, tandis que abattage est généralement utilisé pour désigner des actions liées aux arbres, aux animaux, à la construction, etc.
Pouvez-vous, s'il vous plaît, me dire s'il s'agit d'une erreur ou bien si le dictionnaire est correct et que abattage peut réellement désigner un tissu ou papier pour atténuer la lumière ?
voici les définitions d'abattage dans deux dictionnaires en ligne :
Le Robert
Larousse
Merci d'avance pour votre aide !

Un dictionnaire ? Quel dictionnaire ?

Is this a real question? Abattage is too far from abat-jour, I find it unlikely that a dictionary would confuse both.

Dans quel dictionnaire as-tu trouvé cette définition ?
Comme tu le dis dans la question, elle définit plutôt un abat-jour.
Cette définition est totalement erronée, voir le dictionnaire de l'Académie française :

ABATTAGE nom masculin
Étymologie : xiiie siècle. Dérivé d’abattre.

Action de couper des arbres sur pied. On commencera l’abattage des pins en novembre. Abattage à la scie, à la cognée.
Marque de domaine : mines. Action de détacher la houille, le minerai de la veine, la pierre de la carrière. Avoir de l’abattage, se dit d’un mineur, d’un ouvrier, qui accomplit beaucoup de travail dans une journée.
▪ Par analogie. Marque de domaine : théâtre. Autorité, prestance et entrain nécessaires à un acteur pour jouer et s’imposer dans son rôle. Avoir de l’abattage, ne pas manquer d’abattage.
▪ Spécialement. Pop. Faire de l’abattage, se livrer à la prostitution de manière fort active. Maison d’abattage, maison de prostitution.
Action de tuer des animaux en vue de la consommation ou par mesure de précaution. L’abattage des bœufs au merlin ou au maillet. L’abattage des chiens enragés.
Fig. et fam. Violente réprimande, forte semonce. Il a reçu un de ces abattages !


